# Parsing XML file with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<sparql xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#'>
        <head>
                <variable name='s'/>
        </head>
        <results>
                <result>
                        <binding name='s'>
                                <uri>http://data.open.ac.uk/podcast/c9ddc42f6e1db95f59c83312d62da0ee</uri>
                        </binding>
                </result>
                <result>
                        <binding name='s'>
                                <uri>http://data.open.ac.uk/podcast/18873effb6c38ed83a7522ffb7c61c1b</uri>
                        </binding>
                </result>
        </results>
</sparql>
```

I want to get the uris from the document. I tried these commands:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("file.xml"))
doc.xpath("//uri")
```

but it returns nil.

However, if I modified the file to this:

```
<results>
                    <result>
                            <binding name='s'>
                                    <uri>http://data.open.ac.uk/podcast/c9ddc42f6e1db95f59c83312d62da0ee</uri>
                            </binding>
                    </result>
                    <result>
                            <binding name='s'>
                                    <uri>http://data.open.ac.uk/podcast/18873effb6c38ed83a7522ffb7c61c1b</uri>
                            </binding>
                    </result>
            </results>
```

The above commands return the uris correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace of the element you're trying to select. In the first document this is `http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#`, inherited from the root-node. In the second document it works, because you're removed the namespace declaration by removing that root node.

The good news is because your namespace is defined in the root node Nokogiri will automatically register it for you, and you should be able to select the `<uri>` elements with

```
doc.xpath("//xmlns:uri")
```

Comment: Alternatively, use the `css()` method (which ignores namespaces), i.e. `doc.css('uri')` or use the nuclear, destructive approach of `doc.remove_namespaces!` and then your original code will work.